# Convert PHP Query to Laravel in Controller

Tags: php, sql, arrays, laravel

Can someone convert this php code to something like this in Laravel.

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT birthday, count(*) FROM person group by birthday;");
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {
      $yearvalues[$row[0]] = (int)$row[1];
  }
```

Like this:

```
$female = Enroll::select(DB::raw("SUM(tot_enroll) as count"))
            ->orderBy(DB::raw('sy'))
            ->groupBy(DB::raw("(sy)"))
            ->where('gender','=', 'Female')
            ->get()->toArray();
            $female = array_column($female, 'count');
```

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple,

You can convert your sql query to query builder in laravel like this:

```
DB::table('person')->select('birthday',DB::raw('COUNT(*) as count'))
                   ->groupBy('birthday')
                   ->get();
```

In your case, You have forgot to select `sy` and `gender` so `orderBy`, `groupBy` and `where` do nothing so try this code to get your data.

```
DB::table('enrollments')->select(DB::raw('sy','gender','SUM(tot_enroll) as count'))
                   ->where('gender','=', 'Female')
                   ->groupBy('sy')
                   ->orderBy('sy')
                   ->get();
                   ->toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

I assumed your model name is User. Then you can write this way.

```
User::select('birthday')->groupBy('person')->get()->count;
```